# Switching to wrong keyboard and no options available

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I installed a Lubuntu 20.04 in a virtual machine inside a MacBook Pro - USA keyboard. When I saw the keyboard was wrong, I set a default USA keyboard and deleted the Brazilian one. Sometime later, Lubuntu changed my keyboard back to Brazilian ABNT... I suspect it was after standby mode. Anyway, I tried to reconfigure through Terminal but didn't work. Then I tried again by Input Method Configuration, but it's empty, no input items and no one to add:
(here suppose to have a screenshot)
How can I set a simple USA notebook keyboard and set the file do read only so it can't be change without my will?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.. Keyboard layout can be changed as per https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html however that makes changes to LXQt so will take effect after you're logged in, and I wonder if your issue is your original install set `sddm` to something different to what you changed later in LXQt settings. (`sddm` is not part of LXQt)  I then wonder if you're talking about fcitx.. but I'm lost sorry.  Provide URLs for where the pictures can be found.

Comment: I am sorry I can't provide better info, to help you to help me. I did reinstall fcitx and it fixed my keyboard, but fcitx does not open anymore, and after restart, the keyboard is back to Brazilian again. That's annoying because make it hard to deal with terminal, everything is about typing in the terminal in those Ubuntu flavors that smells like s* :@ sorry you have to hear this... kinda tired. Don't know what is sddm. Will take new screenshots when I could have fcitx working again... maybe I am to dumb for Ubuntu...

Comment: FYI:  There is some non-english support available at Lubuntu's discourse https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ but I don't see Brazillian, but I'd hope people who deal with multiple languages can better help you anyway.  With `fcitx` not opening, I'd compare what you re-installed with what was there originally; was anything not re-installed, if from a different (3rd party or other) source configs may have been overwritten.. Providing details from logs (/var/log/apt/history.log) can remind you what changes were made, let alone `history` itself

Comment: I reinstalled using Muon package manager, but it seems it's not just reinstall to make it work, have to purge files... I will work again on this tomorrow, will try to collect some logs, thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: Muon is a package manager, but any package changes by command, package tools like Muon, or the Discover store are all found in the apt logs  (Discover can also installs snaps, which will be recorded elsewhere).  If you install a package that clashes with an installed package.. it can cause packages to be removed.. The following maybe useful to know what was installed by default for Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-desktop) listing only Lubuntu packages placed on the main Ubuntu base found in all Ubuntu 20.04 systems.

Comment: I was working in a Mint installation, now I on this Lubuntu again. So using the LXQt tool pointed by @guiverc is possible to fix the keyboard, hope won't change anymore. But why there is Fcitx Configuration in Preferences? There is a lot of fcitx packages and removing just the main is not enough. Will try to understand better this package...